# Read all wtmp logs and write them to a .txt file

Tags: bash

I want to read logs ,which I copied from `/var/log/`, with the command `last -f` and add them to a .txt file. The problem is that are multiple wtmp files in the directory and I want to add all of them to the .txt file. My code doesn't work because only one wtmp file will be added to the file.
Here is what I have done so far:

```
cp /var/log/wtmp*.xz ~/test  #copy the .xz archives

unxz -d ~/test/*.xz    #unzip the archives 

last -f ~/test/wtmp* >> ~/test/log.txt 

#add the content of the unzipped archives to a new .txt file(this line doesn't work properly)
```

I hope that somebody can help me!

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

can you do this?

```
for i in ~/test/wtmp*; do 
  last -f $i >> ~/test/log.txt ; 
done
```